# How to use OpenImages dataset to train binary model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, file-io

I am trying to use the [Open Images dataset](https://storage.googleapis.com/openimages/web/index.html) to train a binary CNN model (Orange vs. Not Orange).
I use the OID v4 toolkit to download images of few classes both in train and test.
Now I'm stuck with how to conert the multiclass shape in each directory to a binary.
I believe I need some tool to change the subfolders (=classes) name.

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded using os and shutil packages to manipulate the directories as requested.
TXS.